# Java-Unable to get MAC Address for Ubuntu Device using getHardwareAddress()

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ubuntu, tomcat6, mac-address

i have the following code to extract MAC Address for my Ubuntu device & i am putting the MAC Address in database. This code works fine In windows PC where as the same doesn't work in Ubuntu Device . The database field gets empty. My Application is a web application. I am taking the war file & putting that in the tomcat server which is there in my Ubuntu device.

```
 public static String getMACAddress()
  {
    StringBuffer strMac = new StringBuffer();
    try {

        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        // InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.46.53");

        /*
         * Get NetworkInterface for the current host and then read the
         * hardware address.
         */
        NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);
        if (ni != null) {
            byte[] mac = ni.getHardwareAddress();
            if (mac != null) {
                /*
                 * Extract each array of mac address and convert it to hexa
                 * with the following format 08-00-27-DC-4A-9E.
                 */
                for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
                    System.out.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : "");
                    strMac.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "" : ""));
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Address doesn't exist or is not accessible.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Network Interface for the specified address is not found.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return strMac.toString();
         }
```

I have also referred this([Java - Getting MAC address of Linux system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595479/java-getting-mac-address-of-linux-system)) link.

My Ubuntu device uses both LAN & Wifi connection .

Hope my question is clear. Please help ...
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is almost a duplicate of [Why does java NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress return empty byte array on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485526/why-does-java-networkinterface-gethardwareaddress-return-empty-byte-array-on-win) but it's reversed Linux/Windows so I supposed I'll try to answer it.

It looks like you're getting the loopback interface in the address variable, which doesn't register as having a hardware address since it isn't associated with hardware.  Try making sure you're getting an InetAddress associated with network hardware.  The linked thread has an example of iterating over the list.